# PyQt5 not creating new dialog

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, dialog, pyqt5

im working with PyQt5 for the first time, i have a simple login window and when a user succesfully logs in i want it to destroy the current dialog and create the new one.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    def LoggedIn():
        if ui.checkSQL() == True:
            print('working')
            login2IG = QtWidgets.QDialog()
            ui2 = Ui_Dialog()
            ui2.setupUi(login2IG)
            login2IG.show()
            # loginPage.close
        else:
            print('not working')
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    loginPage = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_loginPage()
    ui.setupUi(loginPage)
    loginPage.show()
    ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(LoggedIn)
    # ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(loginPage.close)
    # ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(login2IG.show)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

the objects and windows work, but it just doesnt create the new window like i need.

[heres a video of what happens](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/557744058102185987/661537066517266434/vokoscreen-2019-12-31_06-49-04.mkv)

Answer (score 0):

managed to fix this myself, when clarifying the second dialog, do it under

```py
loginPage = QtWidgets.QDialog()
```

so heres the new code

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    def LoggedIn():
        if ui.checkSQL() == True:
            show_popup("Success", "Welcome, " + ui.username2DB.text())
            loginPage.close()
            login2IG.show()
        else:
            show_popup("Failed", "Please try again")
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    loginPage = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    login2IG = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_loginPage()
    ui2 = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(loginPage)
    ui2.setupUi(login2IG)
    loginPage.show()
    ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(LoggedIn)
```